# Why am I being asked to review a suggested edit for a locked post?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, locked

I see the yellow box next to "review", and click it. It offers to let me review suggested edits. But when I get there, the only option available to me is "Skip". Why is it offering for me to review it if I can't do anything about it?

[This](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24180) is the suggested edit in question.

Is this a case of a robo-reviewer making a dummy review before I got the chance to click it?

Comment: The question is now locked, but yeah, it's silly for it to appear in the queue. It's probably something that should be brought up on MSE.

Answer (score 4):

This must be due to the fact that only mods can edit locked posts.  Both the suggested edit and the first review did indeed take place before the lock.  I don't believe this is a case of robo-reviewing, either.

Anyway, I've reviewed the suggestion myself, so it's now off the queue.  As to whether or not this is really a bug, a dev may have to address that.